# How does LINQ know what data is being processed? How does LINQ know which DataProvide it should use?

Tags: linq

Please clarify things I learned if something is wrong please explain.

LINQ is language integrated query which means i can query whatever data I want. (whatever providers were made for - and there is lots of them: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/02/28/link-to-everything-a-list-of-linq-providers.aspx)

AFAIK LINQ cannot make connection which means if you want to connect to for example SQL server you need to do it with ADO .NET. If you want to open XML file you need to use XmlDocument xmldoc open function etc.

So the source for LINQ that is gonna be queried is most time some kind of collection. Each time you are using the same syntax to query that collection (LINQ syntax) and somehow it's being translatted to XML / SQL one in the background.

1) How does LINQ know which DataProvider it should use.

2) Are there any data sources that LINQ can do more specific operations that are not occuring in other data sources? For example you cannot use syntax A on XML data source but you can use syntax A on SQL data source? Or it's 100% compatible everywhere?

Best regards

Comment: You are looking at the work of `IQueryable<T>` and  `IQueryProvider` in your examples.

Comment: Thanks now I understand it, but does it mean that there might be some specific LINQ query syntax for LINQ to SQL provider that cannot be used in other LINQ queries?

Comment: If there is an extension methods that can only be hanlded by that specific provider, then yes (for example, the `Include` extension in EF).